# How do I add GET data into an anchor tag so when users click it the data shows up in the URL?

Tags: php, html, get

I have a anchor tag and I would like it to pass GET data into the URL so I can access that data from a php script.

Here is an example

```
<a href="template.php" GET="product1"/>
<a href="template.php" GET="product2"/>
```

The above code does not work so I imagine that is not how it is done.

What I am trying to do is pass the GET data to template.php so it can display things depending on what the user clicks and what get data is sent.

Comment: you want to send data or value from this page to template.php ?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a querystring with a key that has meaning to you (I chose "item") and assign it the product key as the value:

```
<a href="template.php?item=product1">Product 1</a>
```

Now when a user clicks on that link you will have a `$_GET` variable of `product1`:

```
$item = $_GET['item']; // product1
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<a href="template.php?value=<?php echo $_GET['product1']; ?>">product1</a>
```